# Rails Overriding Gem Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am working with a gem in my Rails app that has a controller located in `<gem_root>/app/controllers/<gem_name>/things_controller.rb`. I need to override (more specifically, extend) one of the actions in this controller. I have created a file at `<rails_root>/app/controller/<gem_name>/things_controller.rb`. RubyMine can see the original `ThingsController` and suggests it in auto-completions, but I cannot get the Ruby interpreter to override it:

```rb
# <rails_root>/app/controllers/<gem_name>/things_controller.rb
GemName::ThingsController.class_eval do
  def new
    super
    # My code to extend super
  end
end
```

This results is an unitialized constant error:

> uninitialized constant GemName::ThingsController

I have even tried copying the gem into `vendor/` and directly requiring the original file at the top of the override file, but this doesn't fix the issue. I am used to working with gems that have code in `lib/` but not gem members in `app/`. It seems that `app/` isn't exposed to the host app by default. How do I override this controller?

Comment: What does the code look like inside the gem controller? Can you extend it using a concern? Do you possibly need to use an initializer?

Comment: I dug into concerns more, but I ended up using an override. It frustrates me that there isn't a clean way to just extend the action method while retaining the content of super, but for my needs now I can just replicate the overridden code.